# How to abstract over serializable objects being either remote or local in Rust?

Tags: serialization, rust, enums, rpc, abstraction

I have an enum to represent nodes being either local (referring to the current node) or remote, in which case communication happens through RPC calls:

```
pub enum Node {
    Local,
    Remote(SocketAddr),
}
```

I have a struct `DB` which represents a local database. I need to serialize this `Node` enum because it is used as metadata to determine where certain key value pairs are stored (either locally or remote). I store this metadata in the same database as the rest of my data so `Node::Local` refers to the very database it is stored in.

I want the deserialized node enum to contain a reference to the very database it was taken out of so that I could turn that `Local` variant into `Local(DB)`. Then I would have the same semantics for `Local` and for `Remote` variants in that they both contain enough information to execute `Node.get(key)` and `Node.insert(key, value)` operations.

With the remote variants, I would just open a connection to the `SocketAddr`, and make a RPC request, but with the `Local` variant I have to pattern match in a place where I have a reference to the local database, and apply special logic instead of being able to generally say `Node.get(key)`. The fundamental problem is that `Node::Local` does not contain enough information to perform a request against a local database while the `SocketAddr` in `Node::Remote` is enough to perform RPC calls.

I could solve this by making a custom deserialize method where I passed the current `DB` as a reference to that deserialization method, but I wonder if there are other good ways to solve this problem.

Comment: how about a `trait`?

Comment: That still wouldn't solve the problem of having to serialize it. Even if I did not work with an enum but instead with trait objects, those trait objects would still need to contain the necessary information to perform requests upon being deserialized. For the socketAddr this is not a problem, but I cannot serialize the entire database, hence why the local trait object would not be able to perform db operations without external information.

Comment: Sounds like you are going to realize why local and remote aren't trivial things to abstract across.

Comment: I just miss some information here. Why Node::Local lacks information? why not make it contain the necessary information?

Comment: @Netwave the OP doesn't want to provide a minimal example, so I'm guessing, but they have the `Node` inside of the `DB` struct. The problem is that the information that `Node` needs is the containing `DB` itself. It's a classical circular reference issue. It can be solved in Rust, but circular references are a pain in any language. I'd encourage avoiding it. I'd probably make `DB::get(key)` call `Node::get(key, local_db)` and avoid the whole mess.

Comment: @Shepmaster yea I fully realize that, and in the internal impl Node methods I still will need to match on the local & remote variants. But I'm mostly wondering about deserializing those node enums while also making them contain all necessary information. Maybe my title doesn't quite reflect that though.

Comment: > Why not make it contain the necessary information

That is the central point of the question here. How exactly do we make Node::Local contain the necessary information after deserialization?

And @Shepmaster's explanation illustrates the problem somewhat, but it's a bit opposite: ideally the DB struct would be contained in a Node enum, so that Node.get could internally access the DB. The DB represents a local embedded datastore on a Node of a distributed database.

But those node enums themselves also serve as metadata which is why they are stored in the DB. A bit self referential.

Comment: *those node enums themselves also serve as* — what happens if you stop making one thing play so many different (conflicting?) roles?

Comment: Well they play those two roles because I want to be able to go from that stored metadata to an object i can call get and insert methods on. Separating those concerns is what I suggest as a possible solution in my post, by having an enum for serialization, and another enum, which contains a reference to the DB object, allowing me to call .get and .insert on it. That second enum would be created by that custom deserialize method which would take the serialization enum and a reference to the current DB as inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up representing this distinction as enums. With separate enums for serialization and actual work, because I couldn't serialize the reference to the local database, if you don't have a need for serialization, you can of course elude the NodeRepr enum:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum NodeRepr {
    Local,
    Remote(NodeRef),
}

pub enum Node<'a> {
    Local(&'a LocalDB),
    Remote(NodeRef),
}
```

The node enum then has impl methods delegating the necessary method calls to either the localdb or the NodeRef methods through match statements.

```
impl Node {
    pub async fn get(&self, key: String) -> Option<String> {
        match self {
            Node::Local(db) => db.get(key),
            Node::Remote(noderef) => noderef.get(key).await,
        }
    }
}
```

This way of handling things allows us to still retain the information of whether or not a node is local or remote so we can use this information everywhere in our code when necessary. Which is useful because you generally don't want to always hide the information of whether or not something is local or remote.

If you do always want to hide whether a node is remote or local to enforce code cleanliness for example, you can work with trait objects, where you'd have the LocalDB and NodeRef both implementing the same trait.

A trait is especially useful because it allows the addition of new node types (outside of local & remote) without having to change any old code. With enums, code that expects there to only be two distinct enum cases will break upon the addition of new node types. Limitations of trait objects can also be overcome by applying classic OOP patterns like the visitor pattern.